# How can I redirect Windows COM port output to a file?

Tags: windows, serial-port

Is there a simple way of redirecting serial port output to a file, that I can put into place on a test Windows desktop system without changing any code?

I'm trying to debug a problem in a serial receipt printer module and I don't have the real device handy today. I don't want to start making any changes to the code if I can help it, I just want to capture what is currently being output at the moment so that I can review it in a file.

It's Windows XP, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Following Dan's reply I found this, http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/ , which let me watch the output that was going to the com port and log it to a file. Perfect.

Comment: Have a look at the recommendations for this serverfault question: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/17403/free-software-to-monitor-serial-port-communication/

Personally I prefer the Free Serial Port Monitor: http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/free-serial-port-monitor-product-details.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google led me to [RS232 Data Logger](http://www.eltima.com/products/rs232-data-logger/) - I haven't tried it, but if it does what it says on the tin it should be OK for you. *Edit: it appears to be incoming, not outgoing. Might be worth a try though :-)*

Comment: Thanks Dan. It let me to their Serial Port Monitor, which is capturing something. However I didn't factor that the app/com port component itself would expect some kind of feedback from the device before it would work - it might be that this whole approach is a bust without the receipt printer itself. :-)

Comment: Serial Port Monitor did the trick Dan. I was able to watch output going to the receipt printer even though it wasn't plugged in, once I'd sussed it out a bit. Many thanks!

Comment: This is not a logger, this just is a RS232 terminal: during logging the port is busy, so you can not log the transaction from host to host. This is just a serial port terminal to file.

Answer (score 40):

Another option is through command line:

```
type com1: >> data.log
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it works. Why is the least-simple answer the accepted one? This answer right here doesn't need any programs to be installed; It just works with what comes with the Windows command line.

Comment: @E.T. maybe people are scared of hairy chested mode

Comment: This works only in big chunks and with up to 20s delay.

Comment: How to adress serial port with a number greater than 4?

Comment: `type com7: >> data.log` is no-go for me. Running as admin too.

`"com7:" is not a recognized device. Access is denied.`

Comment: I believe the errors occur when the `COM1` port doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to set the baud rate, data bits or things like that just run the mode command beforehand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mode

Answer (score 8):

Another option: Use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and [turn on logging](http://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/888-how-to-create-a-log-file-of-your-putty-session.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could run the printer module in a VM. VMWare allows you to redirect serial ports to files and named pipes.

Comment: Oh wow - how cool. The machine is already a VM - I didn't realise I could redirect the serial comms that way. I'll give that a try - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to VMWare, [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (& [Virtual Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/)) can also [redirect a COM port to a text file](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2005/10/18/482316.aspx) and setup is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the control pandel, printers, you can add manual printer and install dummay one
So you can printing to a file for example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I originally tried something like this but found that my app wouldn't talk to the com port if it thought it was involved with a Windows printer. I'm not ruling out that I was doing something wrong, though!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you can redirect COM ports but you can use [com0com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) for that kind of job.

For example, you can *pair* (COM1, COM2), so you can write to COM1 and read from COM2.

Answer (score -1):

If you are developer use Serial Port component from .NET or if you don't are a developer and only want get information to file use windows HyperTerminal